# How do i label cells in a mat file and save it in another mat file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a mat file of 732 x 1 DOUBLE named as EnginePower. I used the mean function to find the average value of my engine power, i would first like to compare all the values against my mean value and those that are lower than the mean i would like to label it as -1 and those higher than mean as 1 in another new mat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF YOUR DATA IS A CELL

```
% lets say you have a variable called "var1" in the mat file

load('your_mat_file.mat')
var1=cellfun(@(A) sign(A), var1,'UniformOutput', false);
save('new_mat_file.mat','var1')

%if you want to change any variable in the mat file
clear all
load('your_mat_file.mat')
var_names=whos;
for i=1:length(var_names)
eval([var_names(i).name,'=cellfun(@(A) sign(A), ',var_names(i).name,'''UniformOutput''', false);'])
save('new_mat_file.mat')
end
```

IF YOU DATA IS A DOUBLE

```
% lets say you have a variable called "var1" in the mat file

load('your_mat_file.mat')
var1=sign(var1);
save('new_mat_file.mat','var1')

%if you want to change any variable in the mat file
clear all
load('your_mat_file.mat')
var_names=whos;
for i=1:length(var_names)
eval([var_names(i).name,'=sign(',var_names(i).name,')'])
save('new_mat_file.mat')
end
```

FOR ANY OF DATA TYPES IF YOU WANT ANY OTHER CONDITION BESIDES THE SIGN, CHANGE:

```
var1=sign(var1);
```

FOR

```
var1=(var1<'your_cut_value').*-1+(var1>'your_cut_value').*1;
```

Comment: sorry to ask this, if i used the above code am i only limited to just one value in the mat file ?

Comment: @TK Alive no. you can pick any variable in the mat file. do you want this to also be automatic? changing every variable to -1, 1? or do you know which variables are inside so you can basically just replicate var1 line code. The last option is the easiest one

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 732 values in the mat file all in a single column ranging from 0 to 70 and my average is 21. I would like those below 21 label as -1 and above 21 label as 1. Is this possible? i tried to look through the help but doesnt seem to find any related.

Comment: @TK Alive, I did not tried the last edit but it should be close to that.

Comment: I got this error Error using cellfun Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.

Comment: So you are not using cells then. could you make a whos of your loaded data and edit it in your post?

Comment: sorry to ask but what do you mean by make a whos of my loaded data ? sorry i'm very new to matlab

Comment: just type "whos" in the command line after you had loaded the data and copy the result here. make sure you do "clear all" before. So: clear all; load('your_data.mat'); whos

Comment: Name                 Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  EnginePowerDT      732x1              5856  double

Comment: that is a double and not a cell. please change your question. I will edit the answer

Comment: sorry for the mistake and thanks for your answer really appreciate it !

Comment: if the answer helped please accept it at the left top corner.